# "undefined method `pry'" error inside rails container although pry-rails gem is installed and required

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, pry-rails

I am running public ruby on rails web app docker image (gitlab) inside the container that I initialize with `docker compose run --service-ports --detach [SERVICE_NAME]` command.

My goal is to debug the specific function inside image's source code using `binding.pry` breakpoint. To avoid problems with initial `bundle install`, I install nessesary `pry-rails` gem using `docker exec [CONTAINER_ID] /bin/bash` && `gem install pry-rails`.

I am getting an `undefined method` error although `pry-rails` gem is installed and required.

Corresponding logs from `docker attach` instance:

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log <==
  
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `pry' for #<Binding:0x00007ff556ce52b8>
Did you mean?  try):
```

Here is the confirmation that `pry-rails` is installed:

```
root@3cbe23da9b57:/# gem list | grep pry-rails
pry-rails (0.3.9)

root@3cbe23da9b57:/# gem which pry-rails
/opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/pry-rails-0.3.9/lib/pry-rails.rb
```

`pry-rails` is required inside the `Gemfile` using the following code block:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-rails', '~> 0.3.9'
end
```

`gem env` output:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.4.14
  - RUBY VERSION: 3.0.6 (2023-03-30 patchlevel 216) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /root/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.local/share/gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /opt/gitlab/embedded/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
     - ruby
     - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/gitlab/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0
     - /root/.local/share/gem/ruby/3.0.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => true
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin
     - /opt/gitlab/bin
     - /assets
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your docker container (based on the log file you quoted from) is in the production environment, so will not be loading the gems from that `:development, :test` block. You can confirm `pry-rails` is not loaded with: `Gem.loaded_specs.keys.include? "pry-rails"`

Comment: So, how to migrate it into the development enviroment then?

Comment: If I were you I'd (temporarily) move the `pry-rails` gem into the main section of your `Gemfile`?